# Vector instantiation in java

Tags: java, vector

I have a class Fruit in whose constructor I am instantiating a vector(vector of different fruits). And In that class I am writing a searchVector method. I want to invoke that method from another class searchFruit but if I create an object of the Fruit class, a new vector gets initialized. When I call the searchVector method, the vector is empty(as new vector gets created) and hence the search fails. Is there a way that I could call the searchVector method from searchFruit class.

```
class Fruit{
  Vector v;
  Fruit(){
      v= new vector();
  }
  public Fruit searchVector(String fruit){
     //Searches Fruit
  }

}   

class searchFruit{
   Fruit apple = new Fruit();
   apple.searchVector("Apple");
}
```

Or if I want to write the search function in the searchFruit class how do I pass the created vector to that class.

Comment: There's somewhere that u add fruits on the "v" vector?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: You may want to know about static members. Also look at access control.

Comment: You want that the vector exist of every instance of the `Fruit`? Perhaps you want to make your vector static!. Also don't use vector!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you probably don't want to use a `Vector`.  You probably want an `ArrayList`.  Vectors use a lot of heavy handed synchronization that is simply unnecessary in almost all cases.

As for your question, it's a bit hard to answer as is because it is unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  I suggest that, when programming, you spend a bit more time thinking about your problem domain and understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

For example, you seem to be writing a program that deals with collections of fruit.  In that case you probably need to model at least two types of objects.  Your fruit, and your collection of fruit (for simplicity let's refer to it as a fruit basket).

A `Fruit` will probably have at least a name (apple, orange, etc.) and possibly some other information (size, weight, color, etc).

A `FruitBasket` will have a `List<Fruit>` as well as some useful methods for interacting with your collection of `Fruit`, such as adding fruit, removing fruit, and searching for fruit (of course, these methods are all implemented by any `Collection`, but this looks very much like homework so we'll breeze past that.

As it stands, your design is sufficiently confused that it's hard to point at any one specific thing and say "That's your problem!"  Take it back to the drawing board and try to model it out in terms of real world objects.

Comment: I am using threads and hence I used vectors. I am declaring the vector static but when called from the searchFruit class its creating new vector.